# Who was the first to coin the terms of soft and hard selection?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, population-genetics, population-biology, history

Soft and hard selection are sometimes used with different definitions. I have been told that at first place hard and soft selection has been defined in the following way:

- soft selection: Each deme makes the same contribution to the next generation
- hard selection: Different demes make different contribution to the next generation

Who first described these concepts? What was the first paper?

Comment: Wallace, B. 1968 "Polymorphism, population size,and genetic load"?

Comment: At least in his 1975 paper "Hard and Soft Selection Revisited," Wallace says that he was the first to introduce the terms hard and soft selection in his 1968 paper that I cite above.

Comment: @falsum I think you can make an answer from your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's Wallace, B. 1968 "Polymorphism, population size,and genetic load" In R. C. Lewontin *Population Biology and Evolution*. Wallace also discusses his distinction between soft and hard selection in his 1975 paper "Hard and Soft Selection Revisited" ([JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2407259)).

Comment: Note also [Christiansen 1975](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2459633?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) who is quite an early paper. Actually I was wondering between the who would be the first to talk about selection softness. Thank you +1